# TMPSyntaxMemo: получить слово до каретки

Tags: delphi, строки

Есть компонента `TMPSyntaxMemo`, как получить слово расположенное до каретки ввода (слева от каретки)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашел исходник компоненты, вопрос отпал сам собой)
собсно код, может кому пригодится.
Слово - набор букв или цифр англицкого алфавита.

```
Var
  s,s1:string;
  i:Integer;
begin
  s1:='';
  s:=Memo1.Lines[Memo1.Range.PosY];
  for I := Memo1.Range.PosX downto 1 do  //цикл от положения каретки до начала строки
  if ((ORD(s[i])>=48) and(Ord(s[i])<=57))or((ORD(s[i])>=65) and(Ord(s[i])<=90))or((ORD(s[i])>=97)and (ORD(s[i])<=122)) then //проверка. условие верно пока символ может принадлежать слову.
  Begin
    s1:=s[i]+s1;//На момент выхода тут будет само слово.
    Inserter.wordstart:=i;//на момент выхода тут будет начало слова
  End else Break;//когда найдено начало слова - обрываем цикл.

Inserter.wordstart - будет содержать номер первого символа в слове от начала строки.
Memo1.Range.PosY - вертикальное положение каретки(в строках, не в пикселах)
Memo1.Range.PosX - горизонтальное положение каретки(см.выше).
```